# Sed multiple capture group substitution on one line of input

Tags: regex, json, bash, sed

I have a file of JSON data that is all on a single line. The JSON has some file paths in that I need to update. Heres a sample.

```
"diffuseTexture":{"name":"Axe_03_diffuse.png","level":1.0,"hasAlpha":false,"getAlphaFromRGB":false,"coordinatesMode":0,"isCube":false,"uOffset":0.0,"vOffset":0.0,"uScale":1.0,"vScale":1.0,"uAng":0.0,"vAng":0.0,"wAng":0.0,"wrapU":1,"wrapV":1,"coordinatesIndex":0,"isRenderTarget":false,"renderTargetSize":0,"mirrorPlane":null,"renderList":null,"animations":[]},"diffuseFresnelParameters":null,"ambientTexture":null,"opacityTexture":null,"opacityFresnelParameters":null,"reflectionTexture":null,"reflectionFresnelParameters":null,"emissiveTexture":null,"emissiveFresnelParameters":null,"specularTexture":null,"bumpTexture":null},{"name":"hammer01","id":"dd00d71c-5865-4574-9437-e2777fef63f0","backFaceCulling":true,"wireframe":false,"ambient":[0.588,0.588,0.588],"diffuse":[1.0,1.0,1.0],"specular":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"emissive":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"specularPower":25.6,"alpha":1.0,"diffuseTexture":{"name":"Hammer_01_diffuse.png","level":1.0,"hasAlpha":false,"getAlphaFromRGB":false,"coordinatesMode":0,"isCube":false,"uOffset":0.0,"vOffset":0.0,"uScale":1.0,"vScale":1.0,"uAng":0.0,"vAng":0.0,"wAng":0.0,"wrapU":1,"wrapV":1,"coordinatesIndex":0,"isRenderTarget":false,"renderTargetSize":0,"mirrorPlane":null,"renderList":null,"animations":[]},"diffuseFresnelParameters":null,"ambientTexture":null,"opacityTexture":null,"opacityFresnelParameters":null,"reflectionTexture":null,"reflectionFresnelParameters":null,"emissiveTexture":null,"emissiveFresnelParameters":null,"specularTexture":null,"bumpTexture":null},{"name":"hammer02","id":"ecfa63fb-6939-4ca6-932c-4413693731dc","backFaceCulling":true,"wireframe":false,"ambient":[0.588,0.588,0.588],"diffuse":[1.0,1.0,1.0],"specular":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"emissive":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"specularPower":25.6,"alpha":1.0,"diffuseTexture":{"name":"Hammer_02_diffuse.png",
```

The part of the data that i'm trying to update are the `.png` references
I want to prefix them with a further path so `Axe_03_diffuse.png` would become `/assets/babylon/Axe_03_diffuse.png` I'm having problems doing the replace because the file input is all on one line. The wild card matchers have been matching the whole input and not breaking properly.

I've been trying different permutations of:

```
cat ./hero.babylon | sed -E "s/(\"diffuseTexture\"\:\{\"name\"\:\")(..*)\.png/\1\/assets\/babylon\/\2/g"
```

This works fine until the `(..*`) wild card group.

Comment: Both answers use another char then `/` for the field sep. This avoids the backslashes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, this could help:

```
sed -r 's|"name":"([^"]*.png)|"name":"/path/to/prefix/\1|g' test.json
```

Since you already know `sed`, I don't think, much explanation is required.

Comment: OK, why the downvote? Please, leave a comment when you downvote an answer. If there is some mistake in answer, that comment will help me correct my understanding too...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command.

```
sed -r 's~(\"diffuseTexture\"\:\{\"name\"\:\")([^\"]*\.png)\"~\1/assets/babylon/\2"~g' file
```

`[^"]*` matches any char but not of double quotes, zero or more times.